# Belman-Ford algorithm in 2d Array

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graph

I've got a problem with applying a Bellman-Ford algorithm to 2D Array (not to graph)

Input array has **m** x **n** dimensions:

```
           s[1,1] s[1,2] ... s[1,n] -> Exit
           s[2,1] s[2,2] ... s[2,n]
           ...
 Entry ->  s[m,1] s[m,2] ... s[m,n]
```

And it is room-alike (each entry is a room with **s[x,y] cost of enterance**). Each room could have also a **negative cost**, and we have to find cheapest path from **Entry to choosen room and to Exit**.

For example, we've got this array of rooms and costs:

```
1   5   6
2  -3   4
5   2  -8
```

And we want to walk over room **[3,2]**, **s[3,2] = 4.** We are starting form **5** at **[1,3]** and must walk over **[3,2]** before we go to **[3,3]**.

And my question is, what is the best way to implement it in Bellman-Ford algorithm? I know that Dijkstry algorithm will not work becouse of negative cost.

Is for each room from [0, maxHeight] and relax all neighbors correct? Like this:

```
   for (int i = height-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            int x = i;
            int y = j;
            if (x > 0) // up
                Relax(x, y, x - 1, y);
            if (y + 1 < width) // right
                Relax(x, y, x, y + 1);
            if (y > 0) // left
                Relax(x, y, x, y - 1);
            if (x + 1 < height) // down
                Relax(x, y, x + 1, y);
        }
    }
```

But how can I then read a cost to choosen room and from room to exit?

Comment: if you want to know the optimal cost at the end, you have to keep save the optimal path. you already know which direction you are going (your if statements) so just save that info while you go... I don't think you can save that data using just your 2d array, you must use another 2d array or just add fields to your current 2d array. you basically need to keep the predecessor value

Comment: A 2D array is one way to represent a graph, it's called an adjacency matrix.

Comment: @turingcomplete An adjacency matrix can be stored in a 2D array, but not all 2D arrays are adjacency matrices. *s* is **not** the adjacency matrix of a graph. It's not even square.

Comment: @Phillip that is true, but you can get around that by treating it as a KxK matrix where K = max(M, N) and fill the new entries with some value that denotes "no path".

Comment: @turingcomplete While that would give you *a* adjacency matrix, it'd still not be the one associated with this problem. The problem's adjacency matrix is (m·n)×(m·n) and does not contain *s* as a submatrix.

Comment: There's a negative cycle in your example. Belman-ford (nor any other algorithm) won't solve it. Potentially, you could walk forever between rooms with -8 and -3 scores to obtain -inifinity,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know how to move on the graph from an array, you can scroll to additional condition paragraph. Read also next paragraph. 
 
In fact, you can look at that building like on a graph.

[image]
You can see like: (I forgot doors in second line, sorry.)
[image]

So, how it is possible to be implement. Ignore for the moment additional condition (visit a particular vertex before leaving).
**Weight function**:
Let `S[][]` be an array of entry cost. Notice, that about weight of edge decides only vertex on the end. It has no matter if it's `(1, 2) -> (1,3)` or `(2,3) -> (1, 3)`. Cost is defined by second vertex. so function may look like:

```
cost_type cost(vertex v, vertex w) {
    return S[w.y][w.x];
}
//As you can see, first argument is unnecessary.
```

**Edges**: 
In fact you don't have to keep all edges in some array. You can calculate them in function every time you need.
The neighbours for vertex `(x, y)` are `(x+1, y)`, `(x-1, y)`, `(x, y+1)`, `(x, y-1)`, if that nodes exist. You have to check it, but it's easy. (Check if new_x > 0 && new_x < max_x.) It may look like that:

```
//Size of matrix is M x N
is_correct(vertex w) {
    if(w.y < 1 || w.y > M || w.x < 1 || w.x > N) {
        return INCORRECT;
    }
    return CORRECT;
}
```

Generating neighbours can look like:

```
std::tie(x, y) = std::make_tuple(v.x, v.y);
for(vertex w : {{x+1, y}, {x-1, y}, {x, y+1}, {x, y-1}}) {
    if(is_correct(w) == CORRECT) {//CORRECT may be true
        relax(v, w);
    }
}
```

I believe, that it shouldn't take extra memory for four edges. If you don't know [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), look at cppreference. (Extra variables `x`, `y` take more memory, but I believe that it's more readable here. In your code it may not appear.)

Obviously you have to have other 2D array with distance and (if necessary) predecessor, but I think it's clear and I don't have to describe it.

**Additional condition**: 
You want to know cost from enter to exit, but you have to visit some vertex `compulsory`. Easiest way to calculate it is to calculate cost from `enter` to `compulsory` and from `compulsory` to `exit`. (There will be two separate calculations.) It will not change [big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) time. After that you can just add results.

You just have to guarantee that it's impossible to visit `exit` before `compulsory`. It's easy, you can just erase outgoing edges from `exit` by adding extra line in is_correct function, (Then vertex `v` will be necessary.) or in generating neighbours code fragment.

Now you can implement it [basing on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm). You have graph.

**Why you shouldn't listen?**
Better way is to use Belman Ford Algorithm from other vertex. Notice, that if you know optimal path from A to B, you also know optimal path from B to A. Why? Always you have to pay for last vertex and you don't pay for first, so you can ignore costs of them. Rest is obvious. 
Now, if you know that you want to know paths A->B and B->C, you can calculate B->A and B->C using one time BF from node B and reverse path B->A. It's over. 
You just have to erase outgoing edges from `entry` and `exit` nodes.

However, if you need very fast algorithm, you have to optimize that. But it is for another topic, I think. Also, it looks like no one is interested in hard optimization.
I can quickly add, just that small and easy optimization bases at that, that you can ignore relaxation from correspondingly distant vertices. In array you can calculate distance in easy way, so it's pleasant optimization. 
I have not mentioned well know optimization, cause I believe that all of them are in a random course of the web.

Comment: Exists well optimization (using that, that graph is planar), but I cannot swear, that I'll find time to describe it. However, question was about easy implementation of Bellman Ford algorithm. Is someone really interested in that optimization? If no, I'll not think about description.